# Parallel word recognition in a Non-deterministic finite automaton in Rust

Tags: rust

I have implemented a simple *NFA* that recognizes words in parallel. All the code is on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/alexfertel/atl).

- A main `recognizes` method tells if a `word` (`&str`) is recognized by an *NFA*. Inside this method, I set up a thread pool and a *channel* and call a `recognizes_in_parallel` method.
- The `recognizes_in_parallel` takes a `word` and a `state` and handles two things:

  1. It spawns a new `thread` each time the transition function results in more than one state, i.e., when non-determinism occurs.
  2. It tells if starting at the `state` argument, the automaton recognizes the `word` argument.
- The `recognizes_in_parallel` method sends the result of trying to recognize the word through the channel.
- The main thread then receives until a `true` is sent or when all the threads have hung up or sent `false`.

I am very new to *Rust*, just finished reading *The Rust Book* a couple of weeks ago, and I want to know if this code can be improved regarding readability, efficiency, and organization.

Are there good quality unit tests that could be written for the parallelization? Can I improve the use of locks here? Can I write less verbose initialization? I think I abused the `Copy` and `Clone` traits, is there a way to reduce their use?

Two things to keep in mind:

- `ThreadPool` is not `Sync`, that's why we need the `Mutex` (or so I understood).
- I don't understand why the following change breaks the code, i.e., it does not halt.

```rust
// Works!!
pool.lock().unwrap().execute(move || {
    root_nfa.recognize_in_parallel(&word[..], root_nfa.start, tx, pool_clone);
});
---
// Does not work :(
let pool = pool.lock().unwrap();
pool.execute(move || {
    root_nfa.recognize_in_parallel(&word[..], root_nfa.start, tx, pool_clone);
});
```

Finally, here's the relevant code:

```rust
// state.rs
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "./state.test.rs"]
mod tests;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Hash, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct State {
    pub id: i32,
}

impl State {
    pub fn new(id: i32) -> State {
        State { id }
    }
}
```

```rust
// symbol.rs
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Hash, Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Symbol {
    Epsilon,
    Identifier(char),
}
```

```rust
// nfa.rs
use crate::{state::State, symbol::Symbol};
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex};
use threadpool::ThreadPool;

#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "./nfa.test.rs"]
mod tests;

const WORKER_COUNT: usize = 1024;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
pub struct NFA {
    states: HashSet<State>,
    alphabet: HashSet<Symbol>,
    start: State,
    transition_function: HashMap<(State, Symbol), HashSet<State>>,
    accepting_states: HashSet<State>,
}

impl NFA {
    pub fn new(
        states: HashSet<State>,
        alphabet: HashSet<Symbol>,
        start: State,
        transition_function: HashMap<(State, Symbol), HashSet<State>>,
        accepting_states: HashSet<State>,
    ) -> NFA {
        NFA {
            states,
            alphabet,
            start,
            transition_function,
            accepting_states,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_transition(
        &mut self,
        source_state: State,
        symbol: Symbol,
        destination_states: HashSet<State>,
    ) {
        self.transition_function
            .insert((source_state, symbol), destination_states);
    }

    fn step(&self, ch: char, state: State) -> HashSet<State> {
        let symbol_states = self
            .transition_function
            .get(&(state, Symbol::Identifier(ch)))
            .expect(&format!("No transition found for ({:?}, {:?})", state, ch));

        match self.transition_function.get(&(state, Symbol::Epsilon)) {
            Some(set) => symbol_states.union(set).cloned().collect(),
            None => symbol_states.to_owned(),
        }
    }

    fn recognize_in_parallel<'a>(
        &self,
        word: &str,
        state: State,
        tx: mpsc::Sender<bool>,
        pool: Arc<Mutex<ThreadPool>>,
    ) {
        let mut state = state;
        for ch in word.chars() {
            let next_states = self.step(ch, state);

            if next_states.len() == 1 {
                state = *next_states.iter().next().unwrap();
            } else {
                let mut next_states = next_states.iter();
                state = *next_states.next().unwrap();

                for &state in next_states {
                    let tx = tx.clone();
                    let child_nfa = self.clone();
                    let word = word.to_owned();
                    let pool_clone = Arc::clone(&pool);

                    pool.lock().unwrap().execute(move || {
                        child_nfa.recognize_in_parallel(&word[1..], state, tx, pool_clone);
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        tx.send(self.accepting_states.contains(&state)).unwrap();
    }

    pub fn recognizes(&self, word: &str) -> bool {
        let pool = threadpool::ThreadPool::new(WORKER_COUNT);
        let pool = Arc::new(Mutex::new(pool));

        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

        let root_nfa = self.clone();
        let word = word.to_owned();
        let pool_clone = Arc::clone(&pool);
        pool.lock().unwrap().execute(move || {
            root_nfa.recognize_in_parallel(&word[..], root_nfa.start, tx, pool_clone);
        });

        let did_recognize = rx.iter().any(|did_recognize| did_recognize);

        // If we don't join here, `rx` would be droped
        // and a thread might try to send to a closed channel.
        pool.lock().unwrap().join();

        did_recognize
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the `Does not work :(` part: the lifetime of a temporary value in a `let` binding extends to the end of the enclosing scope, whereas temporary values in an expression statement (an expression followed by `;`) are discarded at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Rust, and welcome to Code Review.

## File organization

First of all, the placement of test modules is unconventional:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
#[path = "./dfa.test.rs"]
mod tests;
```

The common approach is to either simply put the tests at the end of
the module, or create a folder for the module:

```
- src/
  - lib.rs
  - dfa/
    - mod.rs      # equivalent to src/dfa.rs
    - tests.rs    # can be accessed within `mod.rs` as `mod tests;`
```

Using `#[path = "..."]` is overkill here.  (It also refused to work on
my computer for weird reasons, so I had to relocate the files.)

## Warnings

The compiler emits a bunch of dead code warnings:

```rust
warning: associated function is never used: `new`
  --> src\dfa.rs:18:12
   |
18 |     pub fn new(
   |            ^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: associated function is never used: `add_transition`
  --> src\dfa.rs:34:12
   |
34 |     pub fn add_transition(&mut self, source_state: State, symbol: char, destination_state: State) {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `recognizes`
  --> src\dfa.rs:39:12
   |
39 |     pub fn recognizes(&self, word: &str) -> bool {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^

warning: constant is never used: `WORKER_COUNT`
  --> src\nfa.rs:10:1
   |
10 | const WORKER_COUNT: usize = 1024;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `new`
  --> src\nfa.rs:22:12
   |
22 |     pub fn new(
   |            ^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `add_transition`
  --> src\nfa.rs:38:12
   |
38 |     pub fn add_transition(
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `step`
  --> src\nfa.rs:48:8
   |
48 |     fn step(&self, ch: char, state: State) -> HashSet<State> {
   |        ^^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `recognize_in_parallel`
  --> src\nfa.rs:60:8
   |
60 |     fn recognize_in_parallel(
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `recognizes`
  --> src\nfa.rs:93:12
   |
93 |     pub fn recognizes(&self, word: &str) -> bool {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^

warning: associated function is never used: `new`
  --> src\state.rs:11:12
   |
11 |     pub fn new(id: i32) -> State {
   |            ^^^

warning: variant is never constructed: `Epsilon`
 --> src\symbol.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     Epsilon,
  |     ^^^^^^^

warning: variant is never constructed: `Identifier`
 --> src\symbol.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     Identifier(char),
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

warning: 12 warnings emitted

warning: associated function is never used: `add_transition`
  --> src\nfa.rs:38:12
   |
38 |     pub fn add_transition(
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

warning: 1 warning emitted
```

These warnings reveal two issues:

1. `dfa`, `nfa`, `state`, and `symbol` are declared as private modules
   in `lib.rs`, so they can only be used within the crate rooted at
   `lib.rs`.  Therefore, they produce dead code warnings even though
   their items are marked as `pub`.

- Solution: add `pub` to all lines in `lib.rs`.

2. Instead of using the crate rooted at `lib.rs`, you *re-declare* all
   modules in `main.rs`.  In essence, you have two separately compiled
   crates that happen to share some of their source files, which is
   clearly not what we want.

- Solution: remove the module declarations in `main.rs` and prefix
  module names with `atl::`.  Alternatively, group all `use`
  declarations together, which I prefer: (I recommend the same for
  `use` declarations in other files)

```rust
use {
    atl::{nfa::NFA, state::State, symbol::Symbol},
    std::{
        collections::{HashMap, HashSet},
        iter::FromIterator,
    },
};
```

## `clippy`

Running `cargo clippy` results in more warnings:

```rust
warning: name `DFA` contains a capitalized acronym
 --> src\dfa\mod.rs:8:12
  |
8 | pub struct DFA {
  |            ^^^ help: consider making the acronym lowercase, except the initial letter: `Dfa`
  |
  = note: `#[warn(clippy::upper_case_acronyms)]` on by default
  = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#upper_case_acronyms

warning: name `NFA` contains a capitalized acronym
  --> src\nfa\mod.rs:12:12
   |
12 | pub struct NFA {
   |            ^^^ help: consider making the acronym lowercase, except the initial letter: `Nfa`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#upper_case_acronyms

warning: use of `expect` followed by a function call
  --> src\dfa\mod.rs:43:22
   |
43 |                       .expect(&format!(
   |  ______________________^
44 | |                         "No transition found for ({:?}, {:?})",
45 | |                         *current_state, symbol
46 | |                     ))
   | |______________________^ help: try this: `unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("No transition found for ({:?}, {:?})", *current_state, symbol))`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::expect_fun_call)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#expect_fun_call

warning: use of `expect` followed by a function call
  --> src\nfa\mod.rs:51:14
   |
51 |             .expect(&format!("No transition found for ({:?}, {:?})", state, ch));
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: try this: `unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("No transition found for ({:?}, {:?})", state, ch))`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#expect_fun_call

warning: 4 warnings emitted

warning: redundant clone
  --> src\main.rs:36:15
   |
36 |         states.clone(),
   |               ^^^^^^^^ help: remove this
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::redundant_clone)]` on by default
note: this value is dropped without further use
  --> src\main.rs:36:9
   |
36 |         states.clone(),
   |         ^^^^^^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_clone

warning: redundant clone
  --> src\main.rs:37:17
   |
37 |         alphabet.clone(),
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ help: remove this
   |
note: this value is dropped without further use
  --> src\main.rs:37:9
   |
37 |         alphabet.clone(),
   |         ^^^^^^^^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_clone

warning: redundant clone
  --> src\main.rs:39:28
   |
39 |         transition_function.clone(),
   |                            ^^^^^^^^ help: remove this
   |
note: this value is dropped without further use
  --> src\main.rs:39:9
   |
39 |         transition_function.clone(),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_clone

warning: redundant clone
  --> src\main.rs:40:25
   |
40 |         accepting_states.clone(),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^ help: remove this
   |
note: this value is dropped without further use
  --> src\main.rs:40:9
   |
40 |         accepting_states.clone(),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_clone

warning: usage of `FromIterator::from_iter`
  --> src\main.rs:20:9
   |
20 |         HashSet::from_iter([State::new(1), State::new(2)].iter().cloned()),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `.collect()` instead of `::from_iter()`: `[State::new(1), State::new(2)].iter().cloned().collect::<HashSet::from_iter([State::new(1), State<_>>()`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(clippy::from_iter_instead_of_collect)]` on by default
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#from_iter_instead_of_collect

warning: usage of `FromIterator::from_iter`
  --> src\main.rs:24:9
   |
24 |         HashSet::from_iter([State::new(2)].iter().cloned()),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `.collect()` instead of `::from_iter()`: `[State::new(2)].iter().cloned().collect::<HashSet::from_iter([State<_>>()`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#from_iter_instead_of_collect

warning: usage of `FromIterator::from_iter`
  --> src\main.rs:28:9
   |
28 |         HashSet::from_iter([State::new(2)].iter().cloned()),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `.collect()` instead of `::from_iter()`: `[State::new(2)].iter().cloned().collect::<HashSet::from_iter([State<_>>()`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#from_iter_instead_of_collect

warning: usage of `FromIterator::from_iter`
  --> src\main.rs:32:9
   |
32 |         HashSet::from_iter([State::new(2)].iter().cloned()),
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use `.collect()` instead of `::from_iter()`: `[State::new(2)].iter().cloned().collect::<HashSet::from_iter([State<_>>()`
   |
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#from_iter_instead_of_collect

warning: 8 warnings emitted
```

There are four groups of warnings here:

1. According to the standard Rust naming conventions, [acronyms are
   capitalized as one word in `CamelCase` names](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#upper_case_acronyms), so `DFA` and `NFA`
   are supposed to be `Dfa` and `Nfa` respectively.
2. The argument to `expect` is [always evaluated even if it is not
   used](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#expect_fun_call).  Use `unwrap_or_else(|| panic!(/* ... */))` instead.
3. When a value is used the last time, [it can be moved instead of
   cloned](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_clone) to save allocations.
4. `from_iter` is not supposed to be used directly — [use
   `collect` instead](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#from_iter_instead_of_collect).

## Synchronization model

You created a `bool` channel, sent `false` and `true` values to report
the results of each step, waited to receive a `true` value, and then
waited for all the threads to finish computing, only to get their
results discarded.

This model is inefficient.  Perhaps we can use a `AtomicBool` as the
success flag and make all workers stop when a successful result is
obtained.

## Miscellaneous

Let's go through the code.

This is a scary number:

```rust
const WORKER_COUNT: usize = 1024;
```

Are you sure the system you are working with is actually capable of
running `1024` threads concurrently?  If not, you are probably just
adding the overhead of spawning threads.  A more appropriate value
might be somewhere around `4` or `8`, depending on the system.  See
[Can recursion be done in parallel?  Would that make sense?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/238729).

Instead of constructors like this:

```rust
pub fn new(
    states: HashSet<State>,
    alphabet: HashSet<Symbol>,
    start: State,
    transition_function: HashMap<(State, Symbol), HashSet<State>>,
    accepting_states: HashSet<State>,
) -> Nfa {
    Nfa {
        states,
        alphabet,
        start,
        transition_function,
        accepting_states,
    }
}
```

just mark the fields `pub`.  We don't even need `add_transition`.

When you clone something righteously, use `clone`, not `to_owned`.

Instead of `let mut state = state;`, simply mark the argument `mut`.

Types like `State` are usually defined as tuple structs:

```rust
#[derive(/* ... */)]
pub struct State(pub i32);
```

(Note that I skipped the tests since you didn't post them, but there
are many opportunities for improvement in them as well!)

Comment: Thank you! This is a very thorough and thoughtful answer! Would you mind commenting on these questions?

"Are there good quality unit tests that could be written for the parallelization? Can I improve the use of locks here? I think I abused the Copy and Clone traits, is there a way to reduce their use?"

And also, any suggestions about tests would be very much appreciated! I feel like I upgraded my Rust skills a lot just from reading your answer.

Comment: @alexfertel Glad to be of help!  I don't think parallelism is a big concern when writing tests - just testing the results should be fine.  Some benchmarking may also be helpful.  I briefly discussed the locking issue in the section "Synchronization model", but there are always different options and tradeoffs for synchronization - I'm not an expert on this either :)  I don't really see how you "abused the Copy and Clone traits", so don't worry about that.  Cloning isn't problematic in and of itself; appropriately placed `.clone()`s are nothing to worry about if the semantics calls for them.